# How to Convert JavaScript to pure jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some working JavaScript that I want to convert to pure jQuery. Please help me. Here is my full page code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Test1(){
    w = window.open('test1.html', 'popup1', 'width=800,height=600');
    setInterval("Test2()", 5000);
}
function Test2(){
    if(w != null){
        if(w.frames.length == 1){
            return false;
        }else{
            window.open('test2.html', 'popup2', 'width=800,height=600');
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="Test1();">Test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: "JavaScript to pure JQuery" implies that Javascript is a superset of JQuery rather than vice-versa.

Comment: There's nothing in this code that could specifically be ported to jQuery. It would be completely pointless.

Comment: A better title might be 'How could jQuery improve this code?'

Comment: why? if your js works that's cool. and native js is likely faster than jquery.

Comment: I don't see anything here that really needs jQuery. Is there any purpose you have in mind? Also, use `setInterval(Test2, 5000);` instead to avoid an eval. And where did you define `w`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I'd really change is your click handler.

```
$('a').click(Test1);
```

However, your anchor's `href` attribute points to `#` which is a bad idea. Make it point to a valid resource, and if there is none, use a more appropriate element such as a `button`.

I'd also change this line...

```
setInterval("Test2()", 5000);
```

...to...

```
setInterval(Test2, 5000);
```

You don't want or need quotes there, otherwise JavaScript has to evaluate your string in a fashion similar to `eval()`.

Comment: Thanks, What about Test2 function? Any chances translate to Jquery?

Comment: @Anar jQuery is a JavaScript library. Its code doesn't simply translate to plain JavaScript; more you can leverage it to make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can realistically change is the `click` handler.

```
 $('a').click(function() { /* body of Test1 */ });
```

You can update your selector appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of window.open you could opt for using something like [Jquery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#default)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need much, and jQuery barely comes into it - most people would rather convert jQuery to "pure Javascript", not the other way around!

1. `setInterval("Test2()", 5000);` should be `setInterval(Test2, 5000);`
2. `if(w != null)` - what's `w` ?
3. For real jQuery, wrap it in a `document.ready()` handler

---

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="jquery.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var w = null;

    function Test1() {
        w = window.open('test1.html', 'popup1', 'width=800,height=600');
        setInterval(Test2, 5000);
    }

    function Test2() {
        if (w == null || w.frames.length == 1) {
            return;
        }
        window.open('test2.html', 'popup2', 'width=800,height=600');
    }

    // bind the click handler
    $('a').click(Test1);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">Test</a>
</body>
</html>
```